# How does assigning to a comma-separated list of variables ending in *varname work?

Tags: python

Could someone please explain this code to me?

```
a, b, c, d, *e = map(int, input().split())
```

Why does this work and what exactly is the role of the star operator here?

I know it makes a list of the arbitrarily long number of inputs after d, but how does it do this? Also, from my little understanding of the map function, it takes two arguments: a function and an iterable. Yet how on earth can `input().split()` be an iterable? Thanks in advance and excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: `input().split()` will create a list, which is an iterable. See what `'a b c'.split()` does. But it seems you know what the extended unpacking syntax does, i.e. the star, so what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: May be you should check [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Comment: Just checked it. It was very clarifying, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let's work from the inside out...

`input().split()` will take the keyboard input and return a list e.g.:

with input of `a b c d e f g`, the resulting list would be `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

`map` takes a function and an iterable and passes each element of the iterable to the function, returning a new iterable as a result. In your case, the function `int` is applied to each element of the keyboard input.

`a, b, c, d, *e = ....` takes the iterable returned from `map` and assigns it to those variables. a, b, c and d will be the first four integers and e will be a list of any remaining.